# spring mvc controller Test with Enumeration value

Tags: spring, unit-testing, model-view-controller, controller, enumeration

i'm trying to test this Method :

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/PersonalState/{EmployeeId}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public @ResponseBody Object Update(@PathVariable Integer EmployeeId, @RequestParam EmployeeState     empstate) throws Exception { 
    EmployeeService.updateEmployeeState(entityManager.find(Employee.class, EmployeeId), empstate);
    return null;
}
```

EmplyeeState is an enumeration , the values are saved in db as integer,this is my test Code:

```
@Test
public void EmployeeTest() throws Exception {   
        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.put("/PersonalState/{empstate}",EmplyeeState.PERMANENT)
           .param("EmployeeId", "550"))
          .andDo(print())
          .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk());
}
```

I got this Errror:

```
             Resolved Exception:
             Type = org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException
             MockHttpServletResponse:
             Status = 400
```

I tried to pass the two variables as parameters ,passing only the EmployeeId as parameter but i   still have the same error besides the param parameters  must be both of type String.
        Any Idea?

Answer (score 3):

Problem resolved.
i passed as parameter the enum string value.

Comment: what would you do if the the param is list of enum ?